# How to post ManyToOne and OneToOne entity using JSON format?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, spring-data-jpa

I have `comment` entity which has `user_id` and `project_id` as foreign keys. And comments can have parent-child relation in the same table which is mentioned by `parent_commnent_id`.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch;
import org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table
public class Comment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "comment_id")
    private int commentId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
    private Project projectId;

    @Column(name = "comment")
    private String comment;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")

    private RegisteredUser user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name = "Parent_comment_id")
    public Comment ParentCommentId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ParentCommentId")
    public List<Comment> childComments = new ArrayList<Comment>();

    public int getCommentId() {
        return commentId;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    public Project getProjectId() {
        return projectId;
    }

    public void setProjectId(Project projectId) {
        this.projectId = projectId;
    }

    public RegisteredUser getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(RegisteredUser user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setCommentId(int commentId) {
        this.commentId = commentId;
    }
}
```

I have inserted some data manually

```
INSERT INTO comment (comment, Parent_comment_id, project_id, user_id) VALUES ( 'first comment', null, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO comment (comment, Parent_comment_id, project_id, user_id) VALUES ( 'first child comment', 1, 1, 2);
```

Which returns me this

[image]

But i am unable to post data by postman. I have tried this

```
{
    "comment": "third comment",
    "userId": 2, 
    "projectId" : 3,
    "parentCommentId" : 2
}
```

Which inserts the data but returns `userId`, `projectId`, and `parentCommentId` as null.

and I also tried this.

```
{    
     "comment": "third comment",
     "user": {
            "userId" : 2
        }
}
```

which gives me 500 error.

Comment: have you written any controller class and service class which will return this, next only pass a unique id so that it gives you the data as excepted

Comment: Yes in controller i am passing comment object to repository's save function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply send `userId` and then fetch details based on `userId` from `user` Table(any name you mentioned from user).

why are you sending complete object in post its heavy or you can use `@Embedded` annotation.

hope it will works.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're doing, Spring is expecting your JSON to be something like this:

```
{
    "comment": "Foo bar",
    "projectId": {
        "id": 123,
        ..other properties..
    },
    "user": {
        "id": 1
        ..other properties..
    },
    "parentCommentId": {
        "id": 456
        ..other properties..
    },
    "childComments": [
        {   
            "id": 789
            ..other properties..
        }
    ]
}
```

On the other hand, you're inserting like this:

```
{
    "comment": "third comment",
    "userId": 2, 
    "projectId" : 3,
    "parentCommentId" : 2
}
```

You are clearly defining `RegisteredUser`, `Project` and `Comment`. Spring doesn't really know that the property `userId` in your JSON behaves to the `RegisteredUser` object.

> I have tried this
>
> ```
> {
>     "comment": "third comment",
>     "userId": 2, 
>     "projectId" : 3,
>     "parentCommentId" : 2
> }
> ```
>
> Which insert data but return userId, projectId, and parentCommentId as
>   null.

Why is this happening?
Well, your `Comment` class doesn't define `userId`, `projectId`, `parentCommentId` properties.

That's the expected behavior of the deserializer. If you don't want to manually create a object (i.e.: using DTOs), you have to tell the deserializer to create a instance of the `RegisteredUser`, `Project` and `Comment` (for the parentComment).

To do that, you would simply create the object in your JSON.

Instead of this:

```
{
    "comment": "third comment",
    "userId": 2, 
    "projectId" : 3,
    "parentCommentId" : 2
}
```

Try this

```
{
    "comment": "Foo bar",
    "projectId": {
        "projectId": 3
    },
    "user": {
        "userId": 1
    },
    "parentCommentId": {
        "commentId": 2
    }
}
```

This works, but is much more verbose than the way you're trying to insert. That's one of the reasons I always use DTOs for request / response objects.